# How to call void functions from view .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a button that's supposed to run a SQL query.

```
  <button class="btn btn-info mt-3"asp-controller="MessageCenter" asp-action="Markmessage">Mark</button>
```

there is no forms or any sort of thing that I can use a `post method` for. here is the function that I'm trying to call(this is in my controller by the way).

```
public void Markmessage()
    {

        Messagelookupinfo messagelookup = new Messagelookupinfo();
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection();
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("data source");
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("update messages set messagestatus='MARKED' where messageid=" + messagelookup.Messageid, sqlcon);
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();
        RedirectToAction("Messagelookup", "Messageid=" + messagelookup.Messageid);
    }
```

There is no feedback/confirmation for the user just straight up run the query and reload the page.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @iamaaarianme, what do you want to achieve, click the button then redirect to another view with the message?

Comment: Hi. I want to update the database when that button is clicked and refresh the page. normally there would be a form and i would get the post method in controller but here its a button and thats all. Just like a button click event in winform. im new to asp im lost

Comment: If there is no form, you can just use `<a>` instead of `<button>`, and you can still use the css `class="btn btn-info mt-3"` to make it looks like a button

Comment: that worked thank you. how can i pass a parameter to that method if i use asp-controller and asp-action for the <a>?

Comment: Add a `asp-route-*` tag helper, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @iamaaarianme, if my solution can work, could you please accept it as answer, thanks!

Comment: Absolutely and sorry for the delay . Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple example, you can refer to it.

**View (Messagelookup.cshtml):**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Messagelookup";
}

<h1>Messagelookup</h1>

<div>
    <label>MessageId:</label>
    <h2>@ViewBag.MessageId</h2>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-info mt-3" asp-controller="MessageCenter" asp-action="Markmessage" asp-route-messageid="2">Mark</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class MessageCenterController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Messagelookup(int? Messageid)
    {
        ViewBag.Messageid = Messageid;
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Markmessage(int? messageid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Messagelookup", new { Messageid = messageid });
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]